# How to use a dropdown value as a if function

Tags: javascript

i have a html code as following

tfa_78 is a dropdown list, but build in formassembly, so not able to put it in the code
the value "Test" is just to show myself, that the code in general is running ;)

```
<script>     

var tfa78 = document.getElementById("tfa_78").selvalue;

if( tfa78 == "karte" )
{
document.getElementById('tfa_2448').innerHTML ='<b>Bei karte anrufen.</b> <br>';
} else {
document.getElementById('tfa_2448').innerHTML ='Test';
}
```

my question: it is not working, i do not get the first result, what might be wrong? is the selvalue the right thing to select the dropdown value? before, i used this code with a textfield, that was working, so i guess it is anyhow related to the wrong "get" value argument?

Thanks a lot in advance for your support.

I updated my code already due to few comments as below:

```
 <script>     
 var tfa78 = document.getElementById("tfa_78").value;
 if( tfa78 == 'tfa_2438' ) {
 document.getElementById('tfa_2448').innerHTML ='<b> anrufen.</b> <br>';
 }else {
 document.getElementById('tfa_2448').innerHTML ='Test'+ tfa78;
 }</script>
```

and this is the dropdown code, but i can not change that.

```
<select id="tfa_78" name="tfa_78" title="Quelle?" class="required"><option 
value="">Bitte auswählen:</option>
<option value="tfa_2438" id="tfa_2438" data-conditionals="#tfa_93" 
class="">karte</option>
<option value="tfa_2437" id="tfa_2437" data-conditionals="#tfa_93" 
class="">Test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: thx, set a question and changed the shorts

Comment: The GET tag is completely irrelevant. Please stop adding it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE] - This should include the relevant HTML too.

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected value you should use the property `value`.
The `selvalue` I don't in which language exists. See following:

```js
function change(){
  var tfa78 = document.getElementById("tfa_78").value;

  if( tfa78 == "karte" )
  {
  document.getElementById('tfa_2448').innerHTML ='<b>Bei karte anrufen.</b> <br>';
  } else {
  document.getElementById('tfa_2448').innerHTML ='Test';
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="tfa_78" onchange="change()">
  <option/>
  <option value="karte">karte</option>
  <option value="diem">diem</option>
</select>

<div id="tfa_2448"/>
```

Comment: Hi Alessandro, unfortunately, i can not change the code for the field tfa_78, this is a dropdown from an given field

Comment: You only have to change the keyword `selvalue` with `value`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
    var elem = document.getElementById("tfa_78");
    var tfa78 = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
    if (tfa78 == "karte") {
        document.getElementById('tfa_2448').innerHTML = '<b>Bei karte anrufen.</b> <br>';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('tfa_2448').innerHTML = 'Test';
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Hi Shanu, unfortunately, that doesn´t work, don´t know why, tried the same already.

Answer (score 0):

**Use .value instead of .selvalue;**

```
var tfa78 = document.getElementById("tfa_78").value;
```

**Complete code is**

```
<script>     
    function changeMessage() {
        var tfa78 = document.getElementById("tfa_78").value;
        console.log(tfa78);
        if( tfa78 == "volvo" ){
            document.getElementById('tfa_2448').innerHTML ='<b>Bei karte anrufen.</b> <br>';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('tfa_2448').innerHTML ='Test';
        }
    }

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <select id="tfa_78" onchange="changeMessage()">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <div id = "tfa_2448"> </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Hi Utkarsh, unfortunately, i can not change the code for the field tfa_78, this is a dropdown from an given field

Comment: can you paste exact code or little bit more code...that would help...from what i see .selvalue is the issue

Comment: here is the code for the selector:                                                                                <select id="tfa_78" name="tfa_78" title="Quelle?" class="required"><option value="">Bitte auswählen:</option>
<option value="tfa_2438" id="tfa_2438" data-conditionals="#tfa_93" class="">karte</option>
<option value="tfa_2437" id="tfa_2437" data-conditionals="#tfa_93" class="">Test</option>
</select>

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>  
   
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tfa_78').change(function() {

  //Print Dropdown Text 
  console.log($('#tfa_78 :selected').text());
  console.log($("#tfa_78").children("option").filter(":selected").text());
  
  //Print Dropdown Value
  console.log($('#tfa_78 :selected').val());
  console.log($("#tfa_78").children("option").filter(":selected").val());
});
});



</script>
</head>`